# Creating custom icons within Leaflet Marker (only icon/ keep marker style)

Tags: leaflet, mapbox, markers, icon

I'm looking to adjust the actual icon within a marker rather than replacing the entire marker with a custom image.

If I'm trying to use a custom .svg file for the 'icon' property, how can i force leaflet (through L.Icon or a similar method) to replace what the white icon is while preserving the actual tear drop shape of the marker?

I just want to use my own icon image instead of calling the MakiMarker api. I am open to adjusting to another library/method compared to L.MakiMarker.

[image: Marker Creation]

Below is where I want to pass a custom .svg icon to the icon property.

[image]

Comment: Have you looked into font awsome https://github.com/lvoogdt/Leaflet.awesome-markers this gives you many options.

Comment: @BillChappell Still looking to use my own svg though. Let me know if I'm missing a step here

Answer (score 2):

As you alluded to, you will not be able to substitute your own icon image for one of Maki's since those are being returned from mapbox via their marker API ([see here for details](https://github.com/jseppi/Leaflet.MakiMarkers/blob/master/Leaflet.MakiMarkers.js)). Leaflet MakiMarker is not performing any icon "substitution" but instead offering you leaflet markers based on the Maki icons.

You could grab the default leaflet marker image(it's a pin-drop style if that's what you're looking for) and then modify it with your own icon, save that as an image, and then use that image as specified here: http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.1.0.html#icon